# How to know when a WebView has finished rendering?

Tags: cocoa, webview, webkit

In Apple's WebKit framwork, a WebView that has finished loading its resources sends a `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` message to its `frameLoadDelegate`. However, this only means that resources have been loaded, not that rendering is done… How can I detect that the WebView rendering is done? Among all the delegates of `WebView`, I couldn't find one that has the method I would need…

Comment: I can't imagine any computer these days that is not capable of rendering a webpage immediately.

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer define “immediately” and try again. When the `didFinishLoadForFrame` message is received, I observed many cases where the content was not yet rendered in the view.

Answer (score 3):

I also expected to find everything in the delegate methods, tried using the resource load methods too, counting loads started & ended, but that wasn't reliable either. No stackoverflow answers helped me but someone on Apple's devforums pointed out what seems to be the answer.

WebView posts also notifications WebViewProgressStartedNotification, WebViewProgressEstimateChangedNotification, and most relevantly WebViewProgressFinishedNotification. In my code I observe the notification and then to be sure I call my finished method on the next runloop, ie. with [self performSelector:..withDelay:0] or dispatch_async.

Comment: Hum, I tried `WebViewProgressFinishedNotification` but it wasn't rendered yet. I had considered waiting a bit, but is it **guaranteed** that the rendering will be finished on the next runloop?

Comment: No, I never got an official word, it just appeared to work in my initial tests. My question about this is still outstanding on the devforums and I'm still hoping to get the final word on this issue. If it's not working for you then that's disappointing, and it's likely I'll see the same when I get back around to stress testing this part of my app.